# Why we need IEnumerable<string> before get method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

I just started learning web API using ASP.NET. I created a new project from visual studio and trying to understand MVC folder structure and API calls.

Here what I want to know is: why do we need `IEnumerable<string>` before the `get` method.

In my`ValuesController.cs`,

```
        // GET api/values
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
```

According to the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8), this exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type but think if I have an integer in my database do I need to convert it into string as well?

Comment: If you're return a collection of integers change `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<int>`. `IEnumerable<T>` is a Generic, meaning that it can contain a typesafe collection of a specific type - you just need to specify the type between the angle brackets (`<>`)

Comment: Well, I got the point and another question please can you explain to me the purpose of IEnumerable<> we can do the same using for loop right?

Comment: It has nothing to do with with WebAPI, it's the basic syntax of C#. IEnumerable<string> is the return type of the method, you can put there any type you want.

Comment: If your GET-endpoint should return a collection of numbers instead of a single number, you surely need to return some kind of list, be it `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` or whatever.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you this is what I'm looking for

Comment: One of the purposes of the IEnumerable<> is that you can use it in a Linq query. That can be multiple statements on multiple lines. When that query is converted to a List() (for example), the Linq query will be executed. If you would use List to start with, it would be executed right away.

Comment: @BobLokerse got the point. Thanks for your time

Comment: I guess your question was more of `IEnumerable<T>`? what it is? but posted question was more of return type correct me if I am wrong here

Comment: yup, you are right please can you edit the answer with @HimBromBeere 's comment below. because that was what I actually looking for. Then I can accept the answer.

Comment: I would request @HimBromBeere to write an answer, he will explain it better than me(I am confident about it). Then accept his answer, otherwise I will update mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IEnumerable<string>` is a return type of `Get()` action method. If your api is returning any value then you need to give that type as a return type of a function

> If I have an integer in my database do I need to convert it into
>   string as well?

- **No**, then you can return given integer and return type of that api endpoint will be `int`,

like,

```
    //+ Access Modifier
    //|     + Return Type           
    //|     |    + Function name
    public int Get()
    {
        return 200; //status code for Ok.
    }
```

---

Regarding `IEnumerable<>`:

If you have multiple integers and want to return collection of these integers, then use `IEnumerable<int>`

From MSDN documentation [`IEnumerable Interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.8):

> Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a
>   non-generic collection.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, you can return `IHttpActionResult` with `string` values:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var model = new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    return Ok(model);
}
```

or with `int` values:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var model = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    return Ok(model);
}
```

[`IHttpActionResult` allows you to return HTTP statuses and more.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results) Here are some advantages of using the IHttpActionResult interface:

- Simplifies unit testing your controllers.
- Moves common logic for creating HTTP responses into separate classes.
- Makes the intent of the controller action clearer, by hiding the low-level details of constructing the response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll have a try with this

Answer (score 1):

If your GET-endpoint should return a collection of numbers instead of a single number, you surely need to return some kind of list, be it IEnumerable or List or whatever.